# C# EPPlus (or OpenXml) saving ExcelShape as Image

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, epplus

I want to extract all visual Objects(for now Images and Shapes) from an Excel file.

With pictures its easy since they have an Image Property.
Is it possible to save shapes as an Image file?

```
int i = 0;
foreach (ExcelDrawing item in workSheet.Drawings)
{
    i++;
    var pic = item as ExcelPicture;
    var shp = (item as ExcelShape);
    pic?.Image?.Save($@"C:\MyFile{i}.jpg");
    if (shp != null) {
    // how can I save the shape?
    }
}
```